# Java 8 Functional programming

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, functional-programming

I am looking for implementing little generic functions to perform different operations on tree structure.
Need help in collecting results.

Example:

```
public static <R> R collect(final Constraint root, Function<Constraint, R> function) {      
        if(root == null) { // return here }

        //apply function to current node and collect result here
        function.apply(root);

        // If has more children recurse.
        if(root.getConstraints() != null && !root.getConstraints().isEmpty()) {
            root.getConstraints().forEach(e -> collect(e, function));
        }
}
```

This may be used in situations such as
- collect all nodes with no children
- collect all nodes having children
- collect nodes with satisfies some specific condition.

Comment: It sounds like you need your 'collect` method to return a tree of `R`s...

Comment: Yes, I  kept it R trying to keep it more generic to get List, Set, Array, boolean etc

Comment: what help are you looking forward to? also, while sharing the code, do ensure the example is reproducible.

Comment: “I kept it R” makes no sense when the result is not supposed to be `R`, but a structured type, collection, map, tree, whatever, containing *multiple* Rs. If you want to be flexible regarding the actual return type, you need another function parameter telling how to construct the result or a node of the result structure.

Answer (score 1):

How about a `Map`?

```
public static <R> Map<Constraint, R> collect(final Constraint root, Function<Constraint, R> function) {
    Map<Constraint, R> results = new HashMap<>();
    collect(root, function, results);
    return results;
}

private static <R> void collect(final Constraint root, Function<Constraint, R> function, Map<Constraint, R> results) {
    if (root != null) { // return here }

        //apply function to current node and collect result here
        results.put(root, function.apply(root));

        // If has more children recurse.
        if (root.getConstraints() != null && !root.getConstraints().isEmpty()) {
            root.getConstraints().forEach(e -> collect(e, function, results));
        }
    }
}
```